# Get device token with react native

Tags: push-notification, react-native

Is there any way to get the device token for notifications on demand with react native? It seems, from the docs, like the only time the token is exposed is on the PushNotification register event.

More generally, what's the common practice for handling device tokens?

If one user logs into my app, the app requests permissions from PushNotification, the register event is fired and I can associate that device with the logged in user. So far so good, but if that user logs out, and I break that association to stop the notifications, what do I do when another user logs in? The app already has permissions, so register won't fire again. How do I get the device token to associate it with the new user?

Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems my assumption that the `register` event only fires when the user grants access was the problem. The `register` event will fire in response to a call to `requestPermissions` whether or not the user was prompted. So by requesting permissions and responding to the `register` event when the app loads, you can always get the device id. Like so:

```js
PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('register', (token) => {

  ... store or use the token here ... 

});

PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions();
```

Comment: In case this helps anyone else... the 'register' event never fires in the iOS Simulator. In order to test this you'll need to use a real device.

Comment: Is there a way to access the device token after the register event?

Comment: I don't think so. But it looks like the register event fires every time your app launches, so you can always grab it and store it somewhere for other components to use.

Comment: iOS simulator fires `registrationError` event instead.

Comment: I am running in IOS device `register` is not triggering, my react native version is 0.49 @nicholas

Comment: @achu are you running on simulator?

Comment: I'm running on a device. Both the `register` and `registrationError` events don't fire. `react-native: 0.54.2`

Comment: @Nicholas please check this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421887/cant-get-ios-push-notification-device-token-in-react-native/49422036#49422036